# Is it possible to manually position an ngx-bootstrap tooltip?

Tags: tooltip, ngx-bootstrap

I am trying to manually set the position of an ngx-bootstrap tooltip but have not been able to find a way to do it. The documentation has a placement option which isnt what I am looking for. I have a plottablejs chart and want to position the tooltip where my mouse is so that I can show data relevant to the location. I tried the dynamic html option and setting an absolute position on a span with the X/Y coordinates of my mouse pointer but that didnt work.

The tooltip definition:

```
<ng-template #popTemplate><div [innerHtml]="foobar"></div></ng-template>
<div #chart id="chart" class="chart" [tooltip]="popTemplate"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I found that if I have the tooltip set to use innerHtml and then in the returned html I specify the location in a style section like so:

```
let tooltip: string = "<style>.bs-tooltip-top {left:" + (point.x - 26) + "px !important; top: " + (point.y + 80) + "px !important;} .tooltip {pointer-events: none;}</style>";
```

that I can position the tooltip wherever I want it.  This isnt perfect because I the 26 and 80 are based upon a guesstimate of width/height of the tooltip so it doesnt always align perfectly.